# How to extract key with multiple values into a list of values of length more than 1?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like -

```
dict = { a : { 'b' , 'c' , 'd' } }
```

I want to extract the values from this dictionary.

Expected output  -

```
list = [ 'b' , 'c' , 'd' ]
```

where len(list) should be 3.

If I use other methods I'm getting the output as :

```
list= [ { 'b' , 'c' , 'd' } ]
```

Comment: `{ 'b' , 'c' , 'd' }` is a set. Convert `set()` to `list` like `list({ 'b' , 'c' , 'd' })`

Comment: I'm getting that dictionary as an output of a function from a package. I can't do much about it. From that I want to get the expected output to do further things.

Comment: What @StephenRauch meant was to do something like mylist = list(dict['a'])

Comment: Just what are the "other methods" you are trying? We can guess what your problem is but we can't be sure unless you explain your attempts. And what exactly could your dictionary be like--will it definitely have one key with one value being a set with three elements? Your question is not clear as it is now.

Comment: Do you have more than one key on the dictionary and want all values as single list?

Comment: @czr I have one key with multiple values in { }

Comment: @RoryDaulton 
for value in dict.values(): 
    dictlist.append(value)

This is what I did

Comment: Instead of using .append(value), use .extend(value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, **never** name your variables after classes. For example, use `d` instead of `dict`, `lst` instead of `list`. If you can't think of a comprehensible replacement, append an underscope to it (`list_`).

Your dictionary has one key. Assuming you do not know the key advance, one way to retrieve the value in your dictionary *as a list* is to iterate the values via `iter`, return the first one via `next`, and convert to `list`.

```
d = { 'a' : { 'b' , 'c' , 'd' } }

res = list(next(iter(d.values())))
```

Result:

```
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct format of your dict should be:

```
dict = { 'a' : { 'b' , 'c' , 'd' } }
```

and as Shailyn Ortiz suggested you can get expected output by doing:

```
list(dict['a'])
```

Answer (score 1):

[dict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) is a reserved keyword for dictionary mapping and must not be used as a variable.

In addition to the previous answers, another way to do this:

```
test = { a : { 'b' , 'c' , 'd' } }
for k , v in test.items():
    print(list(sorted(v)))  #converting a dict to list can "un-sort" items

#Output:
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I tried to upvote but stackoverflow won't consider the votes cast by those whose reputation is less than 15.